# PySpark - Check if column of strings contain words in a list of string and extract them

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to check if items in my lists are in the strings in my column, and know which of them.

Let say I have a PySpark Dataframe containing `id` and `description` with 25M rows like this:
[image]

And I have a list of strings like this :

```py
technos = ["SQL", "NodeJS", "R", "C++", "Google Cloud"...]
```

I would like to check, for each description in my dataframe, which items from the `technos` list are found.

In output, I would like something like:
[image]

Everything I tried until now has failed.

I tried using UDF and a python function with a `for loop`, but since it doesn’t leverage Spark distributed computing it can't scale with big amount of row.

I recently tried using `pyspark.sql.Column.contains` followed by `pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter` but the filter step is taking so long just for one "techno" and 1M description.

Is there a way to optimize the `filter` ? I saw something with `.join` but I don't understand how it can work in my case.

Is it even possible to optimize such a processing with Spark ?

Answer (score 3):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
technos = ["SQL", "NodeJS", "R", "C++", "Python"]
phrases = ['mastering C++ Python', 'Being SQL master', "working with R"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(technos, StringType())
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(phrases, StringType())

df_exploded = df1.withColumn("items", F.explode(F.split(F.col("value"), ' ')))
df_exploded.show()

+--------------------+---------+
|               value|    items|
+--------------------+---------+
|mastering C++ Python|mastering|
|mastering C++ Python|      C++|
|mastering C++ Python|   Python|
|    Being SQL master|    Being|
|    Being SQL master|      SQL|
|    Being SQL master|   master|
|      working with R|  working|
|      working with R|     with|
|      working with R|        R|
+--------------------+---------+


df_exploded.join(F.broadcast(df), df.value == df_exploded.items).groupBy(df_exploded.value).agg(F.collect_list(df.value)).show()

+--------------------+-------------------+
|               value|collect_list(value)|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|      working with R|                [R]|
|mastering C++ Python|      [C++, Python]|
|    Being SQL master|              [SQL]|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Here is an example, the key to optimize your performance is to broadcast your technos which I hope won't be very large and you use join to collect all the keys present in your description

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, however I'm afraid this solution can't work because some of the technos are composed of multiple words (e.g. `google cloud`, `apache airflow`, ...). I will edit the question to mention it.

Comment: @Agudolive just change the join condition to df.value.contains(df_exploded.items) then it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is done in Scala, but the same logic can be applied on Python as well (very simple syntax);

First of all, concatenate your original list: `[SQL, NodeJS, R, C\\\\+\\\\+]` to something like this: `(SQL)|(NodeJS)|(R)|(C\\\\+\\\\+)`.

In Scala, I use: `Array.mkString("\"(", ")|(", ")\"")` and I store this in a variable, say `expr`.

Then, assume the dataset is called `df` and contains:

```
+---+----------------------------------------+
|id |desc                                    |
+---+----------------------------------------+
|1  |Being SQL master and knowing basics of R|
|2  |Mastering Python and C++                |
|3  |Nothing                                 |
+---+----------------------------------------+
```

You can use `regexp_extract_all` as below:

```
df.withColumn("technos_found", expr(s"regexp_extract_all(desc, $expr, 0)"))
```

And gives this:

```
+---+----------------------------------------+-------------+
|id |desc                                    |technos_found|
+---+----------------------------------------+-------------+
|1  |Being SQL master and knowing basics of R|[SQL, R]     |
|2  |Mastering Python and C++                |[C++]        |
|3  |Nothing                                 |[]           |
+---+----------------------------------------+-------------+
```

NOTE: The `\\\\` in `+` symbol is very important, as `+` is used for other purposes in `regex`.

I hope this is what you need, good luck!

Comment: I found using scala one, the 1st in the group is ignored. eg. 
```val invalidAgreementsContainedWords=List("is_deleted", "ridiculous", "ignore", "ignored").mkString("\"(", ")|(", ")\"").toUpperCase ; 
.withColumn("blah", regexp_extract(upper(col("myCol")), invalidAgreementsContainedWords,0))
.show(100,false)

the "is_deleted" can not be extracted out ```

Comment: found the problem. maybe the original answer needs a bit adjustment too.       the mkString function call: the start and end parameter should not have the double quote (the escaped double quote) so it should be ```val blah = List("is_deleted", "ridiculous","ignore","ignored")..mkString("(", ")|(", ")")```